How to customize the border and dropdown icon color for a single QSelect in Quasar
I'm working with Vue.js and Quasar, and I want to customize the border and dropdown arrow color of a single QSelect component that is in outlined mode. I want to apply a custom border color and change the color of the dropdown arrow, but only for a specific QSelect, not for all instances of QSelect in my component.
Here's the code I'm using:
:deep(.q-field--outlined .q-field__control:before) {
  border: 1.25px solid var(--primary); /* Change the border color */
  transition: border-color 0.36s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

/* Target the dropdown arrow */
:deep(.q-field__append .q-icon) {
  color: var(--primary); /* Change the dropdown arrow color */
}

/* Optionally, change the icon color on hover */
:deep(.q-field__append .q-icon:hover) {
  color: var(--secondary); /* Change the dropdown arrow color on hover */
}

The issue is that these styles are being applied globally, affecting all QSelect components in the scope. I want to limit these styles to a single QSelect by using a custom class or any other method to prevent all QSelect components from being styled in the same way.
How can I apply these custom styles to only one QSelect instance?

There are some ways to achieve this. First of all, did you declare this styling inside <style> tag of the component? If yes, then add scoped to it; <style scoped> (scoped styles apply stylings only to the current component) To make sure it will target only this q-select tag, the best solution is to add a custom class to the QSelect tag <q-select class="custom-selector" .....> , and then inside <style scoped> or your styling file, add:
.custom-selector {

//your code here

}

